# Burninate the [web] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web) is way too broad.

It could currently include any sort of web programming, which could apply to (as a guess) about half the questions on Stack Overflow. Its tag description says not to use it, yet there are many questions created each day with it.

Can we burninate and/or blacklist it?

I mean, if [[web-development] is gone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131138/is-the-web-development-tag-useful/140497#140497)...

There are currently over 41,000 questions, maybe some server-side twiddling (@_@)?

Comment: ...I agree, but why do I feel so reluctant...?  Yes, it's broad, but there are some gems in those categories.  Could you indicate a handful which you think are exemplary and a handful which you think wouldn't stand up with just the web tag?

Comment: @Makoto I don't think which are exemplary really matters. I feel that a total of 0 of them would 'stand up' with **just** the web tag. I mean, what type of results one would expect if looking for [tag:web], unless you **want** to see 3 million questions (1/2 the questions on SO).

Comment: @Makoto No question could stand up with just the [tag:web] tag. "Something to do with the Internet" is an extremely broad range of topics that can only be used as a meta-tag in a programming context anyways.

Comment: I'm on board then.

Comment: [Here's 91 questions with only the \[web\] tag](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/142344). At the very least, we probably need to manually tend to these.

Comment: @Dukeling If the tag gets destroyed, they'll all be remapped to [tag:untagged] so it's not like they'd be difficult to find anyways. But I went through and closed/deleted quite a few questions off that list.

Comment: Question: `internet` is (in most senses) more broad than `web`. Should we keep that around?

Comment: @PaulDraper No, we shouldn't.

Comment: [tag:web] is up to 13.6k, what's the status on this?

Comment: There are also 7 questions for [tag:non-web]

Comment: would you mind updating this post with answers to 4 questions from https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/320317 ? We now have a ~definition of meta-tags so we can make this proposal *obviously* valid

Comment: Just bumped this post, as (obviously) nothing has been done. Hoping it gets some new attention, especially given this post currently sits at +66/-0

Comment: @animuson is there any possibility to just zap the tag from existence?

Answer (score 26):

I think the question you first have to ask is whether or not [web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web) and [web-development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-development) are synonymous in this situation. Personally, I say get rid of it. Most of the questions tagged with [web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web) are also tagged with [django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django), [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), [joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/joomla), etc.. Basically, the tag isn't helping anybody if it encompasses every web technology.

Let it burn.

Comment: My thinking wasn't really that they were synonyms (but then again, [so] is a programming site, so (on-topic) web questions are probably mostly web dev questions), but rather that [tag:web-development] is *less* broad than [tag:web] and was burninated for being too broad (i.e. > too broad = too broad).

Comment: Either way, our conclusion was the same. I agree the tag is way too broad.

Answer (score 7):

The hard part is done!

All of the questions that aren't already closed have been re-tagged. There were a few off-topic questions that I flagged, but did not re-tag - I think it's not too scary if these go untagged when you delete the tag.

All that's left is for one of the admins to delete the dreaded tag.

Comment: Ummm... [I still see 9k+ open questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bweb%5D+closed%3Ano) with the [tag:web] tag.

Comment: We're referring to web-_only_ tags.

Comment: I too have been working on some of them. Some of the still-[tag:web]-only questions in that query are probably ones that are flagged for whatever reason.

Comment: That's not exactly the hard part. The [se] team are very hesitant to remove tags from questions in batch, so this tag will likely have to be removed question-by-question. And, [as animuson mentioned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250190/burninate-the-web-tag#comment817_250190), it's not too difficult to locate untagged questions.

Comment: @Dukeling He was referring to [tag:web]-only questions. In fact it sounds like he's rather [for the idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250190/burninate-the-web-tag#comment814_250190).

Comment: @Dukeling I'm not sure you're watching the same channel as we are. I am reporting that the tags were removed, on a question by question basis, mostly by me and @Qix just today. The only remaining questions tagged with `web` are those awaiting closing.

Comment: I'm not sure what 'channel' you speak of, but this request will only be completed once the 9000+ questions containing the tag are tended to, not just the 90 or so questions that had *only* the [tag:web] tag (which, as mentioned above, can either be done with a batch script, which is not likely to happen, or retagged question-by-question). @Qix I'm pretty sure animuson was referring to the general idea that a tag is only useful if a question can stand up with *just* that tag, not that all questions with just this specific tag should be retagged and/or closed (although that's a given).

Comment: The 9000+ questions that already have more than 1 tag can just drop `web`, and that should be the end of that. The remaining 90 or so have been re-tagged with other tags, so that they don't get lost. That is what I meant by "the hard part is done" - the manual labor is finished, and the admins can batch-drop the tag from the rest of the questions. I'm not sure I can be any more clear than that.

Comment: What is your vision of "tending to" the other 9000+ questions, besides just dropping `web`?

Comment: @Dukeling I recommend you re-read all of those comments again...

Comment: Beyond [the homework tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) (which is possibly the best-known inappropriate [so] tag ever), I don't think I've **ever** seen a case of mods / devs batch-dropping a tag, so "yeah, they can simply do that now" is not really as straight-forward as you think. Besides dropping the web tag, one could do any general cleanup required on the question - remove other bad tags, spelling and grammar, formatting, etc. (which you should always do when you're editing an old post anyway), or closing where appropriate.

Comment: And they won't "get lost", they'll simply pop up [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/untagged), as I pointed out earlier.

Comment: @Dukeling: From the [meta-tag:burninate] wiki: `Requests to have a tag "burninated" (or deleted) from the system. Use in case of uncertainty when requesting discussion, or when the popularity of the tag makes manual retagging followed by automatic culling of 0-question tags prohibitively difficult.`

Comment: One of the top moderators pointed out how dangerous such things are here - [Moderators should be able to remove / burninate a tag themselves](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212823).

Comment: First off, most of his concerns regarding burninating a tag have been dealt with here. [tag:web] is **nowhere near** the grizzly [tag:homework] was. Take a look at the [only comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124504/moderators-should-be-able-to-remove-burninate-a-tag-themselves/212823#comment687112_212823) backing up burnination. I feel like you're grasping at straws.

Comment: **You want to burninate the tag in your OP but now you're totally against it**. What gives? This is *exactly* what burninating tags is for...

Comment: @Qix I'm not against it at all, I'm just trying to point out that what you seem to think the "normal" course of action for burnination requests is is **incredibly rare**. "web is nowhere near the grizzly homework was" - yes, that's part of my point. Since we don't appear to be on even remotely the same page, I guess there isn't much point in continuing this conversation.

Comment: I fail to see your argument, then.

Comment: @Dukeling, when you started this thread, what did you set out to accomplish? What did you mean by "Can we burninate and/or blacklist [the web tag]?", because it seems you're against it now.  


You also didn't answer what do you see for the 9000+ questions with other tags. If it's "one could do any general cleanup required on the question", we can do that for questions in any category/tag, why just focus on these 9000? And how is dropping a bad tag contingent on doing "general cleanup" on questions that may or may not need such a clean-up?

Comment: @ArmanH I can't be any clearer than the first sentence of my previous comment. Yes, the sentence you quoted applies to the 9k+ questions. There's at least one thing that we **know** should be fixed in that post (removing the web tag), but editing it out moves the question to the front page and, because editing causes this, we should fix every possible thing that can be fixed in that post (otherwise people just repeatedly make minor fixes to old questions, causing them to fill up the front page, rather than a single edit, causing each to appear on the front page just once).

Comment: What you're proposing should be a whole another project that is separate from the proposal at hand, and should be separately considered on its own. I found this thread because I wanted to suggest dumping the [web] tag too, not because I wanted to edit all 9000+ questions that may or may not have things that need fixing. I am certain moderators can dump the tags without pushing the questions up in the queue, if that's your concern. Anyways, when [web-development] got dropped, no one combed through ALL the posts to edit ALL possible fixes before going forward with it, and neither should we.

Comment: The first sentence of your last comment is that burniating is extremely rare. Yes, and this is the case that warrants that rare action, no? If not, then why did this thread ever get started in the first place?

Comment: "Why did this thread ever get started in the first place?" - because I'm not up to editing 9k+ questions myself, but me simply forgetting about it doesn't help anyone - I could rather post it here for someone who is up to this, or an anonymous group effort, or possibly moderator intervention (but I didn't really expect that). Burnination consists of either manual or automatic removal - this is what I'm proposing. "This case warrants that rare action, no?" - that's up to the moderators. The rest of your concerns has already been address in my earlier comments, either directly or implicitly.

Comment: We're just going in circles. You insist that 9K questions need to be pruned to drop the tag, I say that's irrelevant. My case point is your own example: there was no clean-up for [web-development], and don't see how treating [web] should be any different. Now if we could get some moderators to chime in...

Comment: **"Burnination consists of either manual or automatic removal - this is what I'm proposing"**... Really? Because you're also proposing that *"we should fix every possible thing that can be fixed in that post"*, which is not exactly about burniating or "automatic removal", is it? I think you should find a clear position first, because I'm really confused by your arguments (and not just me, apparently).

Answer (score -17):

I disagree with burning this, although I could probably be convinced otherwise.

For the time being, it appears to be *widely* used as a way for folks who are interested - *or disinterested* - in all things World Wide Web to indicate their preferences, often combined with a good many other, more specific tags. That said, there are certainly people whose area of expertise cuts across many languages and platforms, focusing their skills on the development of web applications...

...which brings me to my point: why do we have [web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web) *and* [web-applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-applications)? Perhaps a better request would be to merge these two.

Comment: I'm disinterested in most things web (unless it's algorithms) (possibly mainly "web languages", actually), but I don't think the [tag:web] tag adds many questions to the 100 or so tags I'm ignoring. Many / most people probably don't use it, and adding it to all things web seems like it would do more harm than good ... which leads me back to [a tag hierarchy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45438/a-proposal-for-tag-hierarchy-on-so).

Comment: No one's adding it to anything, so far as I can see @Dukeling. Questions get asked in it, either by folks who don't know any better, or folks who don't feel like building a tag soup or perhaps both.

Comment: (Greatly) inconsistently using it seems worse than not having it at all, but maybe that's just the perfectionist in me speaking (i.e. either we should aim to edit it into all questions where it applies, or we should get rid of it).

Comment: I'm far more interested in whether or not it synonymizes [tag:web-applications] than I am in whether or not folks have a strict standard for using it - so far as I can tell, it is consistently used for questions regarding programming WWW applications, which really just leaves "too broad" as the primary knock against it. ...and given there's a [tag:windows] tag, picking on the web seems sorta silly.

Comment: The [tag:web] tag seems about the same as using the [tag:windows] tag to mean any program written to run on Windows (as opposed to questions **specific** to Windows, and not related to other OS's - e.g. crashing on Windows, Windows-only functionality / library), which would just be ridiculous. But even if only for questions specific to Windows, it still kind of seems too broad.

Comment: Should I downvote this because I disagree with your disagreement, or should I upvote this because I agree with synonymizing [tag:web] and [tag:web-applications]? `</somewhatRetoricalQuestion>`

Comment: @Shog9 Do you still believe this tag should exist?