# I want to delete the [internet]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

Internet, depending who you ask, means different things in different contexts. It is a vague concept where everyone has their own idea of what exactly it is, and the official definition is too broad to be useful. The questions tagged with [internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internet) are almost about everything, from git to networking to development of sockets, *ad nauseam*. Internet loosely applies to many things, but actually doesn't tell anything about the question.

I can't think of a single question where internet is relevant for the question or about the internet itself that aren't off topic.

This can't be automatized since they need to be reviewed — all the ~1.7k or so questions.

Comment: Your title sounds scary :P, just add `Tag` -> I want to delete the [internet] Tag

Comment: @NewHire: I think it's a bit of an in-joke.

Comment: @NewHire also when writing `[word]` its normally implied that is a tag.

Comment: I laughed out loud about this! The [internet] is very vague indeed.

Comment: I started posting an answer, but converted it into [a more general question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255242/should-we-delete-the-string-and-array-tags-because-they-have-no-experts) addressing this type of tag.

Comment: Related - [Burninate the \[web\] tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250190)

Comment: The new sort of villain has emerged...

Comment: [Have you tried typing google into google?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OqxLmLUT-qc)

Comment: Remove square brackets from your title - your question will become *much* more popular.

Comment: "It is a vague concept where everyone has their own idea of what exactly it is" - I was under the impression that the congress had dispelled all misconceptions by declaring it to be nothing other than a series of tubes.

Comment: Going by your title I would say, click on the [X] button on the top right most corner of your browser to delete the internet.

Comment: 4 days later - and I still laugh each time I see this title on the right of my SO pages :)

Comment: @Lattyware That scene popped in my head the minute I read that title.

Comment: @Lattyware - it's PROBABLY perfectly safe to do that, but why would you take the risk?

Comment: It should be renamed to [the internets]. That covers pretty much everything.

Comment: I find it odd how none of the top 20 questions tagged [internet] have upvotes.

Comment: So after reading all the comments here I haven't seeing the one suggestion that works everytime. Just delete the big blue 'E' icon on the desktop.

Comment: @DwightSpencer wait, don't you have to remove it either way to get internet?

Comment: [tag:publish], [tag:flex], [tag:list], [tag:focus], [tag:confirm], [tag:calculator]

Comment: @bjb568 wow... that's bad :(

Comment: @Braiam Well either way then, one must delete that icon to solve the issue. Oh and can't forget to use hedge clippers v1.0 on the modem cable as well.

Comment: According to RFC 908, [the internet is a game of Robot Finds Kitten](http://dgh.livejournal.com/9534.html)...

Comment: IMO it doesn't need to be burninated as much as synonymed to [networking], so that retaggers who triage [networking] can handle it.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This is a big waste of time. The tag isn't used consistently *at all* - the bulk of the questions are just folks doing... normal things on the Internet. Connecting to it. Writing web pages. Etc.

I deleted a few hundred questions outright. Then I burned the tag.

[image]

Spend your time making [networking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/networking) more suitable for merging into [network-programming] maybe.

But first, [help the widows and orphans](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/untagged).

Comment: Tagging questions with [tag:internet] feels a little like [do it on a computer patents](http://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2014/06/supreme-court-smashes-do-it-on-a-computer-patents-in-9-0-opinion/).

Comment: No more widows nor orphans.

Comment: ... and it's back! Blacklist?

Comment: I just deleted all the questions in it, @Tunaki.

Answer (score 106):

This question also raises the question about other general tags like [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) and [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array) (see [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255242/should-we-delete-the-string-and-array-tags-because-they-have-no-experts)). While general tags like [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) and [array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array) might bring more clarification when tagged with another, more specific tag (i.e. [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)), the [internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internet)-tag seems to bring no more value at all, even when tagged with another, more specific tag (i.e. [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git)).

That's why I vote to remove it. *'Something to do with the Internet'* is simply too general on a website that focuses on a programming context.

Comment: In some cases, it might help, e.g. [java] and [internet] could mean how to use an internet protocol in Java.  Though, this can be replaced with [networking] or [sockets], etc.

Comment: then it should say `[java] [tcp] [sockets] [http]` or something specific, `[internet]` has no semantic without lots of context around it, and even then it is vague.

Comment: I'd leave things like [string] and [array] because there's no other way for a sub-1500 user asking a question about a programming language about which a question hasn't yet been asked on SO. The language tag doesn't exist, a sub-1500 can't create it (and a sub-5 can't even ask on child meta for it to be created), and a question can't be asked with a blank tag.

Comment: [tag:string] should stay; there are a number of string-processing algorithms (things like Levenshtein distance or Rabin-Karp search) with applicability to almost any language, and someone absolutely can be an expert in these string-processing techniques.

Comment: are we on for burninating the [tag:internet] should I begin? @BenVoigt

Comment: @gideon: If you want to look at a handful of questions tagged [tag:internet] and retag with more precise tags, go ahead.  But do so carefully.  You should take the same approach whether it's a bulk retag effort or a single question you came across carrying a useless tag.

Comment: This is crazy. I've looked at the newest questions on the [tag:internet] tag for 5 mins now and I'm seeing garbage-like questions. I've edited 5-7 questions and voted to close at least 3 so far. I indeed vote to burninate.