# Burninate the [locked] tag

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The Tag [locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/locked) has 166 questions as of now.

There is no tag wiki, and not a single user has more than two answers or questions tagged with [locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/locked).

The tag is ambiguous and unintuitive. overall everything tagged with [locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/locked) should be tagged either with more specific tags ([filelock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filelock), [spinlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spinlock), [screenlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screenlock), ...), or not tagged with [locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/locked) at all.

Comment: Ok after browsing through the question with this tag, yes it is a bad tag. good catch Vogel

Comment: Ok, the pun titles on burnination requests have got to at least make sense.  What does "unlocking" have to do with burninating the tag???  I'm downvoting just becausing of that.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I am terribly sorry for not making up a better pun title for this question as I was planning to leave directly after writing this question.. You are welcome to suggest improvements [:

Comment: @Vogel612 you were just the tipping point.  Everyone feels they need to make burninate requests into a pun.... sometimes it works and but sometimes it is just awful.  Not trying to take the fun out of it, but IMO, puns titles only work when it makes sense.

Comment: You need to do a clean/re-tag first before a burnination.

Comment: @psubsee2003 everyone [wants to burn the internet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255169/792066) anyways... so, let them have fun while it's still there.

Comment: The tag "locked" sounds like a state. Are there other stateful sounding flags?

Comment: @HackSaw [tag:ready], [tag:wait], [tag:close], [tag:result], [tag:back], [tag:forward]...

Comment: Funny title suggestion : " Let's burninate this tag! [locked] "