# Blacklist the whole [internet]

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-deferred, blocklist-request

We all agree that [the [internet] should be deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255169/792066), but the task is daunting. The internet is BIG, and to remove it will take time (and votes). So, we may need to blacklist it so the tasks trying to remove the tag from the system (while closing/deleting the ubbercrap) don't fight against the tide of questions. Can we blacklist [internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internet)?

Comment: While you are at it, you can download some RAM...

Comment: @PM2Ring that will take... some time.

Comment: And a lot of floppy disks. But seriously, I wish you well in this endeavour, as I agree that `[internet]` is not a helpful tag.

Comment: @k_g How much deditated WAM do I need to download?

Comment: Oh, only about four liters

Comment: Excellent, release the hounds `ˁ˚ᴥ˚ˀ` !

Comment: @PM2Ring - the fact that gif is hosted on w3schools is pretty ironic...wouldnt be suprised if it was offered as advice in one of their 'tutorials'

Comment: @SW4. Yeah; that gif is probably one of the most useful things on the w3schools site...

Comment: Beware, the `[internet]` detects damage and routes around it.

Comment: Write a virus that replicates itself and then deletes all occurrences of internet. No need to blacklist anything, just let the virus do its job. Eventually it'll delete them all. Don't hold your breath waiting for it.

Comment: Perhaps we can just route the whole [internet] to serverfault or so?

Comment: For what it's worth, I hear terrorists use the internet to communicate. We shouldn't associate with terrorists, so blacklisting the internet seems like a logical decision.

Comment: Let's blacklist trawling for upvotes with catchy titles.

Comment: Well... Goodbye SE then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I [got rid of the tag entirely](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255169/i-want-to-delete-the-internet/287423#287423).

If it comes back, ping me & I'll blacklist it.

Comment: Why is this [tag:status-deferred] in that case? Sounds pretty completed to me.

Comment: @ChrisHayes it is deferred because request was made for [the whole internet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet) - we're not there yet

Comment: Hah. I see the reason now, in any case. I got mixed up between questions and didn't realize this one was the blacklist request.