# Rename [duck-duck-go] to [duckduckgo]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Ref: [duck-duck-go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duck-duck-go).

Reasons:

- Consistent with [webapps.stackexchange.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) which uses the "[duckduckgo](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/duckduckgo)" tag
- In official code and in [DDG GitHub repositories](https://github.com/duckduckgo/), "duckduckgo" is used without hyphens

I'm happy to help if needed (DuckDuckGo staff).

Comment: Corporate name branding is far off the horizon of programmer concerns.  Ask for a synonym instead, keeps everybody happy and doesn't reactivate a bunch of questions that don't need the reviews.

Comment: There are eight (8) questions in this tag, and I just nominated two of them for closing.  Is this really worth our attention?

Comment: @tripleee It's actually a good thing that there are only a few questions: it will be easier and faster to fix it.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, I had to be brought up on meta. I just attempted to create the tag, and I was presented with [a message](http://i.stack.imgur.com/J8zbw.png) telling me to go to meta. "*You are attempting to create the tag [duckduckgo]; however the tag [duck-duck-go] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta.*" See: http://i.stack.imgur.com/J8zbw.png

Comment: If someone would have renamed it instead of asking whether it is worth our time, it might have been done by now.

Comment: I think duckduckgo is actually pretty difficult to read because of it being all lowercase. CamelCase is much easier to parse.

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga: Have you found *any* upper-case letters in *any* tagname yet?

Comment: @Deduplicator No. I'm not implying that it should be CCase. I'm simply implying that all lowercase is hard to read. E.g. maybe hyphens are a good thing. Maybe there is another solution hidden somewhere (I'm not going to look for one, hence commenting instead of researching and answering).

Comment: I've just checked: MathML -> `mathml`, reStructuredText -> `restructuredtext`, OpenGL -> `opengl`. So despite my initial hesitation, I think DuckDuckGo -> `duckduckgo` would only be consistent. I didn't do enough research to feel comfortable posting this as an answer yet.

Comment: @amani when I type it in the address bar I don't type `DuckDuckGo.com`, I type `duckduckgo.com`. It doesn't seem hard to parse at all.

Comment: @TinyGiant typing and reading are different (typing doesn't even require looking at the text). But sure, it is a minor inconvenience (as in, it is unlikely you will be in a situation where you need to proof-read the whole string).

Comment: @thedanotto nobody is forced to any participation in meta. If you don't have the time, it's fine! But don't limit things based on *your* time frame. Asking this kind of question is really fine.

Comment: This discussion hurt to read.

Rename the tag for the sake of consistency. A consistent method of organization suitable for posts relative to categories said post would fall under is quite literally one of the main points...of a tagging system...

Saying that it's hard to read is personal preference. It should not be a deciding factor in deviating from the system norm.

Comment: Aren't 62 upvotes for a post about eight questions somewhat... odd?

Comment: @Bill yeah, I'm flabbergasted.

Comment: It's an interesting question, given that DDG is a bit of an underdog, and asking politely to do something that most people don't think is worth the time. I've upvoted.

Comment: 62 up votes (now 76) for a category with 8 questions, probably people like me who saw this in the sidebar, clicked it out of curiosity and said "Why the F* didn't someone just do this?" Seriously, it makes sense on every level and the request was even worded politely.

Comment: We are engineers here. Isn't it even sort of a professional thing to do - to get stuff like that right? (Upvoted!)

Comment: @Bill Its a "Hot Meta Post" right now.  Also all the comments on what seems to be a non issue is kind of interesting

Comment: @Krill yes, strangely it was on Hot Meta quickly yesterday. Do meta questions go on Hot Network, or how did it get so many views to get on Hot Meta. Curious. And at 85 now.

Comment: An organization has an obligation to maintain their trademark in order to legally preserve it. Stack-Over-Flow should recognize this. I've upvoted simply because I dislike seeing bureaucracy intentionally and effortfully interposed in place of actual helpful effort.

Comment: Clearly this is only being upvoted because it's funny to do so. My vote is evidence.

Comment: @CubeJockey You should upvote [this instead](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255169/i-want-to-delete-the-internet?s=2|2.4329)

Comment: @RayGe You make it sound like I made a feature request. I'm essentially just throwing my $0.02 in the mix (and it appears by some upvotes that some people agree with my sentiment). For the record: I completely agree that the tag should be named with consistency in mind.

Comment: @shannon agreed!  I have upvoted.  I find it interesting that if the naysayers had a tag they cared about, small or not, they would hoot and holler to get it fixed.  Further, it IS about consistency, which is supposedly important around here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a simple reason why this *needs* moderator intervention, or at very least a well crafter plan... more accurately **The Plan™**.

The tag system tries very hard to prevent people from creating useless tags, we warn users before creating a tag, prevent tag creation which differs of only the last 's' (like plural vs singular of some words) and, like in this case, prevents people from creating the same tag twice with the only difference being dashes (-). So, if right now someone wants to create the [duckduckgo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duckduckgo), it will be presented with a error message:

> You are attempting to create the tag [duckduckgo]; however the tag [duck-duck-go] already exists! If you think this new tag should be allowed, raise it on meta

Instead of trying to rename the tag from duck-duck-go to duckduckgo, lets do it **The Right Way™**. Stack Overflow isn't company/product aware, we may use the tags with the same name as the product ([the company is a big no-no](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190914/213575)) so users can identify what you are referencing to easily.

But, like in this case, DuckDuckGo the search engine, as search engine, isn't **[relevant in any programing context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/213575)**, what we, programmers, are interested with is what we can use *programmatically*, be it libraries, binaries, ABI, or, like in this case, API's. Which is my motivation for a counter-proposal: don't rename [duck-duck-go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duck-duck-go) to [duckduckgo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duckduckgo), but rename it to [duckduckgo-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duckduckgo-api). This has the advantage that can be done by *any* user that can create tags (1.5k+), doesn't need moderator intervention (as it doesn't even trips the tag creation error), or a well timed removal of tags circa 00:00 UTC (which is a pain and you can miss the window).

If nobody has any problem, this should be a-go.

Comment: Suffixing every API with `-api` isn't all that useful though...

Comment: @Deduplicator I prefer it that way, since eternity we have the problem of being mistaken as [costumer support of that product/company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/792066)

Comment: @Deduplicator It's not useful when there is no non-API product to consider. When the non-API product is more well known than the API, well...

Comment: So we'll do that because there is no moderator available for this issue?

Comment: The API is one of a few DuckDuckGo programmer-related products, for example there are questions on Stack Overflow about the DuckPAN toolchain (for creating Instant Answers) and DuckDuckGo custom search box. Making sure I understand this correctly, the proposal would be to remove the existing `duck-duck-go` tag and add product-specific tags as necessary, e.g. `duckduckgo-api`, `duckduckgo-search` (or `duckduckgo-custom-search`), `duckduckgo-duckpan` (or perhaps just `duckpan`). Is that a correct understanding? And if so, do others agree?

Comment: @tagawa personally, that would be ideal.

Comment: Thank you for The Plan. I wasn't aware of the company name rule and tagging by product turns out to be better all round.

Answer (score 3):

This question has now over 100 up-votes and only 5 down-votes so far. As I've already commented, using hyphens to separate words in names that are originally written in CamelCase is not the general practice (cf [mathml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathml), [opengl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opengl), [restructuredtext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/restructuredtext), …). It are only eight questions and the change is not likely to do any serious harm.

I'm not sure what we're waiting for any more.

The tag system won't let us create a tag [duckduckgo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duckduckgo) until [duck-duck-go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duck-duck-go) goes away. Therefore, if there are no immediate objections, I'll do what [Braiam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/792066/braiam) [suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314586/please-could-the-stack-overflow-duck-duck-go-tag-be-renamed-to-duckduckgo/314754#314754) and re-tag all questions to use a not-so-similar tag like [duckduckgo-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duckduckgo-api). Then, after the old [duck-duck-go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duck-duck-go) tag has been auto-deleted, I'll re-tag the questions again to [duckduckgo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/duckduckgo) which should then be possible.

If you think that this double-re-tagging is a bad idea just to overcome the restrictions of the tagging systems, please flag this post for moderator attention so they can make it happen directly.

Comment: Thanks for the offer. I was giving it a bit more time to get feedback on my product-specific tags comment. As there's been no objection I've just created [tag:duckduckgo-api] and [tag:duckduckgo-search] which cover the existing questions and are consistent with other tags, e.g. for Google products. Also, because of the no-company-tags rule it's probably OK not to have a general `duckduckgo` tag.

Comment: @tagawa Alright, I think that this is a fine solution, too.