# Merge [wifi] into [network-programming]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

[wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wifi)

I considered a burninate on this but there are some [on-topic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39356079/where-does-access-points-ip-address-come-from-for-wifi-beginap-on-arduino-mkr) that would be harmed by a burninate request. Still, there's a problem that needs to be highlighted here. This tag attracts a LOT of off-topic requests. People are literally treating it like it's [this tag on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-networking).

I've edited the wiki and excerpt to be more like [seo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seo), in that it contains a robust warning when not to use the tag, but I think that the term **wifi** is incorrect here. I would suggest we rename it to **network programming**. It's unlikely to be confused for wifi support, and sounds more like working with programming the wireless networking layer. Finally, with wifi as a redirect it shouldn't confuse people.

Comment: [*"Spend your time making networking more suitable for merging into \[network-programming\] maybe."*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287423) I think this is what we should strive for.

Comment: @Braiam Good idea

Comment: BTW, when Shog said that, he meant for us to clean up the tag first...

Comment: I suppose radio networking has its own issues in addition to those that wired networking has (suppose you'd want to know programmatically what's the current band you're connected to). I don't think a merge is a good move.

Comment: I agree with Lucas, Wi-Fi programming can be really different than network programming. That said, I agree that [wifi] on itself is too broad, but a merge sounds not the proper path to me. A proper tag and blacklist of wifi alone sounds better but I'm unsure on the proper tag name.

Comment: @Tensibai Make a new tag [wireless-programming] maybe?

Comment: Seems an idea, but I'm unsure of the side effects, I didn't go through the questions on the actual tag and how it would clash (or not) with any other network related tag. I was just dropping my thoughts ;)

Comment: The tag is for such a common thing that you'd probably spend the next year or more explaining to people why there is no wifi tag.

Comment: why have the suffix of `-programming`? don't all tags have that suffix implicitly eg `swift-programming`, `c#-programming`?

Comment: @Machavity: _"Make a new tag [wireless-programming] maybe?"_ -- if going that route, probably better to do "[wifi-programming]". "Wireless" covers too much ground, including Bluetooth, Bluetooth Low Energy, GSM, CDMA, IR, etc. in ways that don't really generalize in most cases. That said, I'm not sure about the justification to rename/merge/whatever. For better or worse, there are many tags on Stack Overflow that tend to attract people looking for end-user support; shall we rename them all?

Comment: Agreed with Daniel and Peter. Questions about programming wifi (802.11) need their own tag. 802.11 is a huge set of standards with lots of issues very specific to those standards that would not apply to wireless communication in general, let alone networking in general. I'm not sure that the tag name needs to change at all, but, if it does, it should retain 'wifi' in the name. I do agree that usage guidance needs to be edited into the tag wiki and excerpt, though. I didn't see your edits when I looked at it. Maybe they haven't been approved yet?

Comment: @DanielA.White do you want a [tag:network] tag? Oh, wait we already have, get a shovel!