# This tag needs [debugging]

Tags: discussion, clean-up

The [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debugging) tag has the following description:

> Debugging is a methodical process of finding and fixing bugs in a computer program.

Seems reasonable enough. Based on the tag description, though, this tag is for questions about the process of debugging itself, *not* simply for requesting help debugging a program.

With that said, this tag is flooded with low-quality "help me debug my code" questions. Not only is that contrary to the intent of the tag, it's pretty blatantly "Meta tagging."

I don't think that this tag deserves to be burninated - debugging techniques is a real topic (you can actually be an expert on the topic), and it's definitely on-topic here on Stack Overflow.

My proposal, then: close all of the low-quality questions, remove the tag from "help me debug my code" questions, and improve the tag Wiki to make it more clear that this tag is only for questions about the process of debugging itself.

We *may* also want to consider renaming the tag to "[debugging-techniques]" or something like that.

Comment: I'm not sure that I want to look:(

Comment: @MartinJames Yeah, it's basically become a dumping ground for rubbish questions from new users. It's rather horrible to look at.

Comment: A dumping ground with 38271 questions...

Comment: @Martin Pff, what can be worse than having seen the [malbolge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malbolge) :-P ...

Comment: @EJoshuaS The even worse thing is, that newbs in compiled programming languages (as eg. c++ where I'm mostly active) often confuse _debugging_ with _fixing compiler errors_, because syntax errors is what they mostly meet the first few weeks. Renaming of that tag would be a good idea IMO. Upvoted.

Comment: _debugging techniques is definitely on-topic here on Stack Overflow_? Questions discussing debugging techniques might be better suited for [softwareengineering.se] depending on the question. Definitely is a bit strong in my opinion, if it's on topic and not too broad is heavily dependent on the question, and such a tag might still invite bad questions.

Comment: The tag almost gets one question every hour, by the way. I highly doubt we can burninate it using the normal process. I hope one of the mods feels like doing something like [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287423/7296893) again, else I don't see how we can get rid of this tag.

Comment: If we keep the tag, *definitely* rename it. I'd go so far as to try to come up with a name that doesn't start with the word "debug." It's *far, far* too likely to be misused if it sounds like anything close to debugging.

Comment: @jpmc26 I agree - even with a good tag Wiki, the current name is just begging for misuse (which is probably how it got to be so bad in the first place). A better name would make it clearer what the tag is supposed to be for.

Comment: @jpmc26 Maybe we should have separate tags for the different debugging techniques.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: Finally! That `power-cycling` badge is mine. I can tell everyone it's about physical exercise and kill two birds with one stone!

Comment: @JeroenMostert :-D Well, you know what to do!

Comment: Can we just auto-close new questions tagged with [debugging]?  Just kidding (I think).

Comment: It seems "debugging" was tag-synonym'd with "debugger", which might not be great.  Debugging seems more vague (problem solving with software), as opposed to "debugger" (program is compiled, and problem is with the tool used to debug it)

Comment: I'm all for renaming to something like `debugging-techniques`, but I still don't understand what makes a tag "meta" nor why they "meta tags" are considered problematic.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161229/what-makes-a-tag-meta-and-are-such-tags-inappropriate

Comment: Could a [`[rubber-duck-debugging]`](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/) tag be added? It could be applied to low quality debugging questions by suitably privileged users and would effectively hide the question until the OP's duck certifies that RDD has been completed without resolving the issue(s). (I pity the ducks in therapy as a result.)

Comment: @HABO Couldn't questions like that just be downvoted and closed until they're improved?

Comment: @HABO We already have that... it's the question quality filter! Starting to write a question for Stack Exchange _is_ a rubber duck. So if you really want this... think about ways to improve the quality filter. (I hear the filters _do_ go in therapy regularly, so you'll want to improve their mental strength too :-D )

Answer (score 1):

IMHO debugging is one of the best things to teach someone who does not know yet how to do it. This may avoid all kinds of other questions. People are still debugging by adding `print()` statements (my observation).

I didn't learn debugging in university (ok, that was back in 2001). I used `vi` for editing and compiled on console. When I presented Eclipse to my professor, he didn't know what it is. So there's a need for debugging education and it seems SO is doing it.

I have [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debugging) as the third tag (after [windbg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windbg) of course) that I'm watching, and there are 1500 others watching that tag, too. It shouldn't be a problem of too few participants in the tag.

> this tag is flooded with low-quality "help me debug my code" questions.

Maybe. On the other hand side, it [has questions with 1000 upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debugging?sort=votes&pageSize=15), so there are good questions and lots of helpful answers.

What's missing, IMHO, are some canonical answers that could be used for closing as duplicates. There should really be some longer, more tutorial style answers that explain the benefits of using a debugger and an introduction on

- how to do it in Visual Studio, Eclipse, PyCharm and all the other IDEs.
- on Windows and on Linux
- how to debug exceptions / crashes
- how to analyze performance issues
- how to find the root cause of deadlocks

I am thinking of this: [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). It's a wonderful dupe hammer and we'd need a dozen more of that size.

Comment: The vast majority of questions on Stack Overflow are about fixing code with some kind of problem anyway, though, so I'm not sure what the [debugging] tag actually adds. It makes sense if it's about the process of debugging itself (in which case I think that it should be renamed [debugging-techniques] or something like that to accommodate those questions), otherwise it seems really "Meta" to me. Do you have any examples of "help me debug my code" questions that really, truly need the tag?

Comment: I do agree with creating canonical dupe targets, though, and creating a [debugging-techniques] tag focusing on the actual process of debugging.

Comment: Looks like its time for some Documentation ;)

Comment: @Luuklag: yes, and the [debugging] tag was not accepted for documentation

Comment: While this tag doesn't seem useful on first glance, I do have to admit that sorting by highest voted questions does turn the list into quite a nice guide for debugging features and techniques.

Comment: My contribution to improving things: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems