# What to do with [worksheet-function] vs [excel-formula] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

Today I stumbled upon a question that was tagged with both [excel-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-formula) and [worksheet-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/worksheet-function).

Reading the tag excerpts:

[excel-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-formula):

> This tag is for Microsoft Excel questions where the question or answers are specifically about the structure, syntax, or output of an Excel formula.

[worksheet-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/worksheet-function):

> A worksheet function is represented by a keyword in an Excel formula that performs some action on input and returns output to the calling procedure, either a worksheet cell or another function.

To me there is a clear difference between these two:

- a question tagged with [worksheet-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/worksheet-function) should be specifically about a single function, `=sum()` for example.
- a question tagged with [excel-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-formula) should be about how to write a (complicated) formula combining multiple (different) worksheet functions.

When I look at how the tags are used this difference isn't so clear and there are plenty of questions tagged with both, which could be appropriate but would occur in the minority of cases.

So then the question arises how do we move from here?

1. Make [worksheet-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/worksheet-function) a synonym of [excel-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-formula)
2. Clean up both tags and keep this distinction in place
3. Any other good suggestion?

---

P.S. I purposely didn't spark the debate whether or not questions dealing with Excel that don't include VBA are on-topic at all or not.

Comment: Can you explain why you think we should take action here? Seems both terms are distinct enough to warrant their own tags, and overlapping enough to make a cleanup and enforcing a distinction a lot of work. Leave as is seems like a fine option.

Comment: @ErikA I think doing away with both. For that most people has excel and vba already.

Comment: @ErikA, a lot of work is to be seen, `[worksheet-function]` has just over 1k questions. So in the grand scheme of things that could be considered a reasonably small tag. As for why we should take action: my OCD doesn't approve of such mixed usage.

Comment: @Luuklag A cleanup like you propose would also include moving over questions from [tag:excel-formula] to [tag:worksheet-function]. And that's certainly not a small tag, and would be a lot of work (too much to be feasible for a manual cleanup imo, certainly if there's no real need for doing so).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a VBA expert, but personally I disagree with your suggestion of synonymization; the two are [a bit different](https://superuser.com/questions/166008/what-is-the-difference-between-function-and-formula-in-excel). An Excel formula can be written without using any worksheet function whatsoever (e.g. adding two values, even referenced cell values, together).

There is also the `WorksheetFunction` object in VBA that allows you to work directly with function methods and properties in code. That would definitely not be something appropriate for the [excel-formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-formula) tag to cover/describe. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction for more information.

Comment: As I said there is a difference between the two, I'm aware of that. However users that post questions are apparently not aware. I'm also aware of the `Worksheetfunction` in VBA, but that is something the tag description doesn't mention. Perhaps it should.

Comment: @Luuklag users misusing tags is not enough of a reason to do away with them, IMO; otherwise we might have to do away with [tag:c] and [tag:c++] for all the questions asked that are incorrectly tagged with both. I think the best we can do is update the [tag:worksheet-function] tag to better describe what it is (instead of just saying the same thing as [tag:excel-formula] in a different way) and then try to re-tag questions appropriately as best we can.

Comment: @TylerH "users misusing tags is not enough of a reason to do away with them" try to tell that to Shog: [*The tag isn't used consistently at all - the bulk of the questions are just folks doing... normal things on the \[spreadsheet\]*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287423/792066)

Comment: @Braiam That's an overly broad, blatantly off-topic tag... different situation than this.

Comment: This one is a off topic tag too. Tell me, where are the developers that specialize in any worksheet function? You can find exactly 0. Now, developers that specialize on VBA? Non 0. Tags without specialization shouldn't be tags. Tags creation are for topics that *haven't been asked before*. This tag shouldn't have existed in the first place, because there has been several thousands of questions about VBA.

Comment: @Braiam That's a different conversation; if you'd like to suggest we burninate both of these tags, you should post a question on Meta for it, or alternatively post an answer here as Luuklag did ask for "other suggestions".

Comment: No Tyler, is not a different conversation. You started moving the goal post saying that something that (almost) all developers use was off topic, while I countered that something that only a handful of developers use was off topic. You can't counterargument that misuse isn't a reason to remove a tag saying "but that was off topic tag" without expecting the interlocutor to follow your suit. Now, please demonstrate how misuse is not a reason for moderating a tag?

Comment: @Braiam I'm not moving the goalposts at all; I am saying these two should not be synonymized. You came in with a red herring in the comments and I'm telling you to take that red herring elsewhere while also dismissing your bad example. Please don't put arguments in my mouth such as we should not moderate a tag that is being misused. Like I said before, if you have a separate suggestion for how to handle these tags, post it as its own post.

Comment: @Braiam The number of developers that specialize in worksheet functions and formulas may be few, but certainly not 0. There are a few programs written in my field that have no VBA at all, and are just sheets filled with formulas and data to make scientific predictions (e.g. [HLAMatchMaker](http://www.epitopes.net/downloads.html), not affiliated). You may not like it, I may not like it, but they exist.

Comment: @ErikA sigh... you, along with Tyler seems to be missing the point of my comment. Tag misuse requires the tag to be removed. Full stop. Whatever would be the topic of the tag is inconsecuential. I was just taking a quip at common, but still misguided meta talk that "tools commonly used by developers" no matter the context is on topic. But, let me repeat: **this tag is misused, misuse of a tag is grounds for burnination**.

Comment: @Braiam No, tag misuse does not 'require the tag to be removed full stop'. Tag misuse is one of *several* criteria to consider for tag burnination, but it is not even the most important single criterion for that.

Comment: @TylerH so, why do you think Shog removed the internet tag?

Comment: @Braiam I'm just pointing out that your argument is false, there are worksheet programmers, and __misuse is not one of the [burnination criteria](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071)__. If a tag is misused, that's a reason for a cleanup. Only if a tag meets _all_ criteria, it should be burninated, and if you want to make a case for that, you should do so in a separate question, not here in the comments. As far as I can see, both these tags may be misused often, and may attract content that belongs on [su], but certainly don't meet the criteria for burnination.