# The [website] sucks, especially the [homepage]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The tag [website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/website) is way too broad. It can be applied to almost any [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), or [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) question, but it is currently used on only 5,864 questions. In my opinion, it should either be on all related questions or none of them, and I'm rooting for none.

**Edit**:  <s>[homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homepage) is gone!</s> [homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homepage) was gone, but has since reappeared. Currently, it has 31 questions.

[homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homepage) is quite ambiguous; it has at least three different meanings:

- The initial or main web page of a website.
- The web page or local file that automatically loads when a web browser starts or when the browser's "home" button is pressed.
- A personal web page, for example at a web hosting service or a university web site, that typically is stored in the home directory of the user.

Comment: Nice timing: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258699/the-stack-overflow-homepage-is-over-emphasizing-bad-questions-and-a-proposed-so

Comment: for a second there I was about to tag this question as a rant

Comment: Would upvote twice if I could, once for the request and twice for the title.

Comment: I agree with `website`, but disagree with `homepage`. Homepage isn't that ambiguous and the meaning should be clear from the other tags or from the question.

Comment: @slugster: but what does it add to the question? What help does it provide anyone choosing whether to look at the question?

Comment: Additionally, there have been no `homepage` experts since the late '90s.

Comment: @Charles my _webmaster_ would disagree with you ;)

Comment: I do agree with the OP. They are far too wide in their (semantic?) meaning. And, by the way, i heard the `webmaster` is hosting rpg sessions online :P

Comment: Website is also too easy to use for off-topic questions

Comment: I checked the 35 questions in the [tag:homepage] tag, all of them seem to be about the main web page (index.html). Looks like it is being used correctly now. Do you still think that this tag has to be burninated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expedient solution here is to merge [website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/website) into the larger [web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web), as they both appear to have roughly the same use.

So, I did that. Calling this done for now.

Comment: Now we just need to remove the web https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250190/792066

Answer (score 8):

I agree with burniating the [website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/website) tag. The fact that its current usage guideline is "DO NOT USE. Select some more descriptive tags, like html, css, php, http, etc." kind of tells you how bad it is.

This tag adds no useful information whatsoever; if you've tagged PHP or something like that, then it's a pretty safe guess that you're doing web development. If you *haven't* tagged your specific platform, you *should* have.

I'd like to go a step further and suggest a large-scale cleanup effort followed by burnination.

Comment: This is still relevant in 2017 even though the burninate request was created three years ago. Currently [tag:website] stands at 8000+ questions, and is gaining about 4-8 posts daily: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bwebsite%5d%20is%3aquestion

Answer (score 6):

[homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homepage) appears to have been burninated successfully! Huzzah!

Unfortunately, [website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/website) is still in use—and gaining 2 to 3 questions per day.

Comment: I think this is useful to SO.  Having a well organized house makes us valuable.  But I do agree that there are large problems and small problems.  Further reading:  http://karengridley.com/what-are-your-boulders-pebbles-and-sand/

Comment: It seems [tag:homepage] reappeared.