# Lets Burninate the [website]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The tag description clearly says "DO NOT USE", and recommends using a more descriptive tag (regarding the specific tech used). Despite this, no one reads tag descriptions, and this continues to be used multiple times per day.

On top of burnination, I'd suggest blacklisting it to prevent it from reappearing, given its frequency of use.

Comment: Although I am wholly in favor of blacklisting all DO NOT USE tags, I understand that there [exist reasons not to due to how the tagging system works](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271356/7795130). To help make sure this request is valid, explicitly go over the guidelines on [how to justify tag burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070/7795130).

Comment: I agree with this request.

Comment: Sure, this may be marked as a duplicate, but given that it hasn't been acted on in over 4 years, it's a bit ridiculous to dismiss this so quickly.

Comment: This is worth to discuss again. The other discussion didn't achieve anything.

Comment: For posterity, this is discussion from 4 years ago: [The \[website\] sucks, especially the \[homepage\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258700/the-website-sucks-especially-the-homepage)

Comment: @Braiam Maybe instead of reopening a clear duplicate it would be better to update the original to get some new attention. Maybe include the [criteria for burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070/4916627) that are currently missing (Also missing here)

Comment: @AndréKool "some new attention" that's why I did what I did. If the question is more 4 days old, it would get **no attention**. A '14 question will get no attention doesn't matter how much is edited.