# Untangle the [web] and break the [connection]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

In the process of bringing down the [internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internet), I've found a lot of posts tagged [web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web) and some tagged [connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/connection). These don't seem much more useful.

Comment: Half duplicate of [Burninate the \[web\] tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250190), btw, nice prose

Comment: Only 13,000 question in the [web] tag to individually edit.  I guess you'd better get busy.