# When should a question be tagged with [web]?

Tags: discussion, tags

The SO [web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web) tag has 25,000 questions and almost the same number of followers, yet its excerpt is *extremely* broad:

> Use this tag for general questions related to all aspects of the world
>   wide web. For specific portions, use the specific tag for it, such as [uri], [html] and [http]

The wiki for this tag goes over the history, protocols, Tim Berners-Lee, servers, and is synonimized with [www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/www)

IMO the phrasing of the first sentence of the excerpt, *"Use this tag for **general** questions related to **all aspects** of the world wide web"* begs for it to be misused.

It fails most, if not all [criteria for burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191), and many users, especially new ones, add it to any type of question. Take a look at the [list of questions currently using the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web?sort=newest) and see if there's any common thread among them. I couldn't find any.

As broad as the term "web" is, and and seeing as how it's been applied to just about every type of question, when should it be properly applied? Does this tag need to exist at all?

Comment: I could only imagine it when used with [spiderman](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bweb%5D+spiderman&mixed=0) and I'm not disappointed ....

Comment: It looks like this tag was involved in something called [The great Stack Overflow tag question cleanup of 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012) (now deleted). [The tag wiki was edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7175469/revisions) to include a "DO NOT USE" and a reference to the "great cleanup" post in revision 4. This was rolled back by Shog9 in revision 5. [This was brought up again in 2013](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250190/4639281) to which Shog9 again showed disapproval. So I guess... ask Shog9 how he feels?

Comment: [It was also brought up again in 2015](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283761/4639281)

Comment: @rene: I was hoping it was going to be about Donald Knuth's "literate programming" language called WEB.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WEB).  TeX and Metafont are written in WEB.  I don't even see a tag for that language.  I don't know much about it, but searching on [`web2c`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=web2c) only finds questions with `tex` and `latex` tags.  Of course, `[web-language]` would probably be a better tag name, to avoid attracting false positives from newbies who type `web server` into the tag field or whatever.

Comment: a [tag:web] tag would be as relevant as a [tag:computer] tag or a [tag:programming] tag

Comment: Duh, it should be used whenever a question is posted on the web, of course.

Comment: @Cœur I think you meant the... [tag:programatically] tag

Comment: @TinyGiant well, 2013 Shog9 was kinda naive.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From a tag specific standpoint, this one clearly came back from the ashes. Burnination required.

> When should a question be tagged with [web]?

Never. A question should not be tagged with the [web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web) tag ever.

> Does this tag need to exist at all?

No.

---

From a general tag standpoint, is it time to reflect on the process of removing tags like this? From all the community effort put into these actions, there seems to be some sort of drive to continuously place vague tags onto questions by certain users. Are we missing some sort of signal here? Do these erroneous tags really cause harm? The required repetitive nature of burning the same tag should lead to some sort of reflection about the nature of this process and what roll these tags play.

Comment: More specifically, the tag needs deletion and blacklisting. 25k questions is too much to burninate and for a meta tag like this straight deletion is simpler

Comment: "by certain users" ...Are you sure it's not a ton of users? I would reverse your question, though: why do we allow such low reputation users to *create* tags? If managing them is difficult and bad ones create a lot of work, shouldn't there be a higher bar? I'd also argue that the only signal we're missing is that tags are in general misunderstood and misused. Their main purpose is for searching. That happens in a few ways: users search by them on SO, answerers filter by them when looking for questions, and Google probably uses them for indexing. [tag:web] is not helpful for any of these.

Comment: @jpmc26 - Thanks for your insights. From my analysis it seemed that google does not take tags into account in searches.

Comment: Regarding the process of removing tags like this, there is already an internal effort underway looking at ways to streamline burnination, mass tag removal, and mass cleanup. We are still in the very early stages, though. It is the [Trogdor](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165597/trogdor) chatroom.

Comment: @TylerH - That sounds like a good idea to me. My point though was perhaps we should also look at what keeps causing these messes, and what we can change to prevent them or harmonize with them.