# Tag wiki for "web" tag says "do not use this tag"

Tags: support, tags

I just noticed the tag wiki for the [web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web) tag starts with the sentence "Do not use this tag". It does not, like other tags, mention a reason (do not use this tag for ...). The tag wiki reads:

> Do not use this tag. For questions related to an aspect of the world wide web, use a more specific tag for it, such as [uri], [html], [http] or [w3c].

So I am wondering, if I should not use this tag at all, why is it even there?

Comment: Because people keep using it. A tag won't get removed until it is not on any questions.

Answer (score 2):

The tag is there because it hasn't been burninated yet.
You should not use it.

If you look at the timeline of the Tag Wiki Excerpt, you'll find the [where the "do not use" was added](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19885466). It has this Edit Summary:

> This tag isn't specific enough: [When should a question be tagged with [web]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368821/when-should-a-question-be-tagged-with-web)

So, ask your question with more specific tags.