# Could we blacklist tag [app]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, blocklist-request

The tag [app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/app) has:

- 0 questions
- 1.3k watchers

So it was likely cleaned up in the past. Yet, someone is trying to reenact the tag: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21058559.

As the word "**app**" is one of the meaningless words [triggering rejection in question titles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373415/what-triggers-my-title-rejection), **could we have the tag [app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/app) blacklisted?**

---

<sub>(eventually, we could also blacklist the few other title-rejecting words when used as a tag: [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/error), [website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/website), [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code), [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/question), [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/problem), ..., bug [Shog9 has historically disapproved burninating [website]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260535/1033581) so I'll leave that request aside)</sub>

Comment: I've failed cleaning up the tag a couple of weeks ago because questions were coming in too fast and the cleanup script runs at an inconvenient time for me, and eventually did so with some help of others in SOCVR. I very much support blacklisting it, since it's apparently popping up frequently

Comment: Shog didn't disagree, he simply didn't think it was important. In fact, he made the problem bigger by merging website into it, which was probably because his prior idea of merging was nonstater due the other tag being removed.

Comment: I'm mostly just sympathetic toward folks who might want to ignore the tag, @Braiam. Shocking though it may seem, there are still people who write software that doesn't involve websites.

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing @Shog9, those people aren't the ones answering questions nor being generalist on all the things. Having sane boundaries on knowledge that people are expected to gravitate are the best tags, since most people would agree what it is about.

Comment: I think most folks agree on the meaning of "web", @Braiam; I don't see folks asking questions about spiders, or tholians, or Walter Scott. Are they *good* questions? Usually not. Does that mean we should expose them to more people? Definitely not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Done:

[image: The 'app' tag is not allowed. "App" is short for "application software", a generic term which covers almost everything programmers write. If you're not writing system software, you're probably writing an app. Please choose a more specific tag!]

Answer (score 27):

Please do. I'm always for blacklisting tags that had to get burninated more than once.