# Retag [scriplets] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scriplets/info

The correctly-spelled tag already exists ("scriptlet").

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to merge [tag:scriplet] into [tag:scriptlet] and then add [tag:scriplet] as a synonym of [tag:scriptlet], so that future people that don't check their spelling have the correct tag? (Similar to like [tag:sql-server] has the [synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/synonyms) [tag:sql-srever], as people don't read).

Comment: @Larnu Maybe? Probably? I considered that too, it just bugs me :p

Comment: Well, I think we don't need a plethora of misspelled tags around here. Tag creation has a relatively high rep bar to avoid green users creating them by accident, and there is a prominent popup when you try to create a new tag. Let's just merge it into the correctly spelled one.

Comment: Unless you're looking at the synonyms page for [tag:scriptlet], you'll never see [tag:scriplet] again. If, however, it isn't added as a duplicate, it just takes one person to not bother check their spelling again, and it'll be back.

Comment: @Larnu I am not very keen on catering to people who misspell and then dismiss the popup saying there is no such tag (I am sure it is still used only because it is suggested sooner than the correct one), but if it takes that to get rid of the misspelled tag - count me in.

Comment: *"I am not very keen on catering to people who misspell and then dismiss the popup saying there is no such tag"* don't worry, @OlegValter , neither am I.

Comment: @Larnu yeah... https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo8fa.png It would probably be better if the popup suggested the off-by-one completions as even CLI programs usually do, but I guess the chances of success in proposing this are closer to absolute zero.

Comment: Possibly, @OlegValter , but I'm still of mind that the user is the one at fault here. They've been told that the tag is new, and yet they still decided to introduce it into the site. They're not a new user either, so they *should* know better, and know how the site works. Not reading such a short, succinct, and explicit message is not an excuse there. Such users are probably also ones that haven't looked for a solution to the problem or the problem they have is actually typographical as well so the question is likely to be closed or downvoted; but we're *way* off topic now. :)

Comment: I agree with @Larnu, I think a synonym is the way to go. It's a much less intensive process than burnination anyway, and will automatically retag the questions. At 100 questions currently tagged with [[tag:scriplets]], it would take at least a little bit of time to retag them all to [[tag:scriptlet]], which can be avoided with a synonym.

Comment: @Larnu - yeah :) Just an idea that crossed my mind: to remove the "primary" state from the "create anyway, I know what I am doing button" and add suggestions (clickable, preferably) of off-by-one tags to allow those users to help themselves. But that's a world with unicorns and rainbows everywhere. Anyways, thumbs up to the request (be it processed as merge or synonym).

Answer (score 21):

#### It's a really common misspelling, make them synonyms

This is a really common misspelling: on Stack Overflow, there are [1227 search results for "scriplets"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=scriplets) and [1096 for "scriplet"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=scriplet).  A mistake this common is going to keep coming back (and some people may even believe it's correct).

[scriplets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scriplets) should thus be made a synonym of [scriptlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scriptlet) so that future users making this mistake get the right tag. It will also stop the wrong tag from accidentally getting recreated or the correct tag from being missed by people who think the tag doesn't exist due to the misspelling.

Comment: If it's going to be a common mistake, couldn't we just blacklist the misspeled tag?

Comment: [From other blacklist questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375213/3854787), it seems that it's even possible to add a custom explanation as to why the tag is blacklisted. This could be something like "hey, you're misspelling scriptlet! :)"

Comment: @CássioRenan While we *could*, the overall point is– synonyms are designed **explicitly** for this purpose. The [tag synonyms page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scriptlet/synonyms) reads: "*If you know of common, alternate spellings or phrasings for this tag, add them here so we can automatically correct them in the future. For example, suggest “bike” as a synonym for bicycle, or “sock” for socks.*" This case falls squarely in the intended purpose of tag synonyms.

Comment: @CássioRenan Also of note: blocking a tag is a process that [only site staff/ developers can carry out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95811/how-do-tag-blocklists-work). Synonyms can be handled by the community, and thus (I would argue) are preferable in *most* cases.

Comment: @CássioRenan Did you misspell "misspelled" on purpose? ;)

Comment: @zcoop98 the example on that page doesn't agree: bicycles is a synonym of bikes. Two correctly spelled words, same meaning. Misspells aren't alternative spellings, it's the _wrong_ spelling.

Comment: @Braiam It also happens to be a misspelling *of the plural*. It seems clearly popular enough in usage to me that I really think synonym is the right move here. Going to the trouble of correcting the spelling or burning/ blocking the tag sounds like poorly spent effort when we could just synonymize and be done with it (I would also pedantically argue that common misspellings should fall into the alternate spellings category).

Comment: @zcoop98 there's no such "trouble", a moderator can do this in a single operation. If it appears again, which I doubt it, then we may start looking at next level. But preemptively solving the "problem" is what programmers should avoid doing.