# Burninate or annotate [web-interface]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Summary (to [follow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) [the procedure](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070/3995261)):

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?** → It is definitely ambiguous or not descriptive in most cases. In the questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31197747/3995261), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1984709/3995261), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25256873/3995261), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41323507/3995261), however, it indicates that those don't only involve back-end and those who do mostly full stack should be attracted.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?** → Not quite sure how to interpret this: since it's ambiguous and too general it is probably off-topic as "too broad" but in general it's ok to ask about web-interfaces.
3. **Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?** → again, only in cases where it highlights: "this is not only about back-end" which is probably too broad and should be substituted with more specific tags (html/JavaScript).
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?** → definitely no.

In the original post I explore what the questions tagged [web-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-interface) look like, how I handled a bunch of them and summarize the tag stats (some stuff moved to the answer):

Recently I've noticed the [web-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-interface) tag is out there and seems to be rather pointless. I've raised ~15 flags there, some questions (see links in my answer) were deleted, one is closed and it seems that generally the tag attracts off-topic/too broad questions. In some questions it is rather pointless: in the end, if a question is about html/css/js, it should be tagged so (see links in my answer). [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31197747/3995261) a less obvious example: kinda back-ender's question about front-end. Retagged it with [web-frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-frontend). [Another one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1984709/3995261), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25256873/3995261), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35217748/3995261), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14169325/3995261), [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41323507/3995261), same resolve; untagged and flagged [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19277756/3995261). For [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37821/3995261) (and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5090999/3995261)) I've removed the tag because it's actually not *about* front-end. [A poor question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48054029/3995261), retagged and flagged.

Another type of tagged questions is about doing something via web-interface of a tool or adjusting such interface ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52775526/3995261):retagged and flagged, [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7086019/3995261):retagged). Some of them are tagged pointlessly since they are about the tool and mentioning web-interface is either not relevant or an x-y thing ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39690579/3995261), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49085144/3995261), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21555517/3995261), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40521810/3995261), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9518632/3995261), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34529468/3995261), [7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3173110/3995261), [8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4364402/3995261), [9](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6448612/3995261), [10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9657151/3995261) – untagged each). Some are.. well, more relevant but the tag is useless since a collection of questions about different tools' web interfaces is pointless so mentioning web interface or a specific feature in title is good enough (see links in my answer).

Special cases: a vague [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33294521/3995261) about running batch scripts with web GUI but without server (retagged); a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26777222/3995261) about adding web backend and frontend to an existing app (retagged); a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44995624/3995261) about Android stuff connected to web

The tag has no description yet. It is rather ambiguous or even can be considered a [meta-tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/), can't it? It is not very active, it had 86 questions, including about 10 from this year, before my review.

Looks like it's not a tag to stay, is it? If you beleive it is, please suggest a proper description for it.

Comment: You may want to consider reformatting this post to be a bit less rambling. I had a hard time getting through the questions because it's stream-of-consciousness nature. I do think we should burninate `web-interface`, but I also think we should burninate `web-frontend`, and `web` for that matter. The fact that a software application is hooked up to the World Wide Web is hardly noteworthy these days. Anyway, In that note, you'll notice the four questions you should answer "no" to. If you can answer these in the burnination request, you're well on your way. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: @HereticMonkey right, I've added the 4 answers, would you help me to sort out the case of "this is not only about back-end"? I'll refactor the whole post later so that it less confusing and more brief.

Comment: Related: [Burninate the `[web]` tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250190/burninate-the-web-tag)

Comment: I think we can rely on what I'll call "environmental" tags, like `nodejs`, to indicate whether a tag like `javascript` regards the backend. Other tags (e.g., `asp.net`, `spring`, `wordpress`) can help with other languages/frameworks for the backend. Likewise, there are contextual queues for frontend questions, like `angular` or `reactjs` or even just the combination of `javascript` and `hrml`. If a question is somehow a question which requires categorization on the basis of "which end", they can use the existing `frontend` tag (but as you say, it's likely too broad).

Comment: "What a tangled [web-interface] we weave, when first we aim to mistag"?

Comment: Somebody please step up and propose a save step. I think one can exist but I couldn't come up with one and I don't want to argue a strawman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, [burninated manually](http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/11114/111144096/4088295-5709483615-ozai-.gif) :)

I've reviewed all the 86 questions and un/retagged and/or flagged each one.

There was few groups of questions that I'd like to mention (may be this will be helpful for discussing and burninating tags like [web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web), [web-frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-frontend), [front-end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/front-end) (now burninated), [frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/frontend), [user-interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-interface), [dynamic-websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-websites), [web-site-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-site-project)):

- front-end questions about html/css/js/ajax etc ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42645544/3995261), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52038153/3995261), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52254749/3995261), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5438824/3995261), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12089679/3995261), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14373683/3995261), [7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35102474/3995261)). Those which already have appropriate tags can be untagged right away (automatically, once they have at least one of html/css/js/ajax) because the tag is just doesn't add any specificity while being ambiguous
- questions about specific tools and their web-interfaces which have no reason to be gathered by the same tag and it is good enough to mention web-interface or a specific feature in the title and add a tag of the tool being discussed ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11749150/3995261), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6087076/3995261), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27517753/3995261), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49826605/3995261), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45957086/3995261), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42521715/3995261), [7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40224254/3995261), [8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30691733/3995261), [9](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29492134/3995261), [10](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19708316/3995261), [11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13989210/3995261), [12](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32493596/3995261), [13](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21620225/3995261), [14](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29142148/3995261), [15](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28691859/3995261), [16](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24627305/3995261), [17](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8957878/3995261), [18](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27778757/3995261), [19](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19572713/3995261), [20](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11633878/3995261), [21](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15091395/3995261), [22](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7285781/3995261), [23](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4236246/3995261), [24](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3989753/3995261), [25](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1815814/3995261), [26](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2783994/3995261), [27](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4346513/3995261), [28](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48259996/3995261), [29](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39166006/3995261), [30](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4479828/3995261), [31](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4843068/3995261), [32](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30564871/3995261), [33](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35246933/3995261) – untagged; [34](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7086019/3995261), [35](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52775526/3995261) – retagged)
- ... (will finish review soon)
- some of poor questions that got deleted: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50057312/how-to-write-simple-opennebula-software), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50389581/easy-to-use-mysql-snapshot-management-tool), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45731908/mapping-employees-to-manager-in-bo-4-1), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527930/is-it-extraordinary-that-a-bms-application-does-the-same-thing-slower-than-a-cic), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25403186/web-interface-to-add-periodic-tasks-to-celery-rabbitmq), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45731908/3995261), [7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25403186/3995261) (can't generalize main problems since I don't have reputation to see and review them once again; [6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45731908/3995261), [7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25403186/3995261) were in the 2d group before getting deleted) or closed: [6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52432358/3995261)

I've also proposed a tag description which was accepted:

> please DO NOT USE THIS TAG. If your question is about html/css/javascript, tag it accordingly. If it's about web-ui of an existing tool, just add the tag corresponding to the tool. If it's something different and still on-topic, you might want to use [web-frontend] tag instead. This tag is ambiguous and unhelpful

Later the tag was deleted by somebody.

Comment: Empty tags are automatically deleted by the system (so it's highly unlikely *someone* deleted it manually - the automated process probably killed it off).

Comment: @Zoe yeah, that's what I suspected after another burnination, thanks