# What should we do about [web-site-project]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

With [466 questions in mind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-site-project), this tag is confusingly named [web-site-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-site-project), but its description references Visual Studio Code. Any person watching this tag will be very confused with its broad spectrum of ideas. <strike>My main idea is to make this a synonym of [web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web) (which also seems to have its own broad issues)</strike> Thanks to y'all, I now know that this is a much broader issue on the [web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web) tag and subtags in general.

The tag's description:

> Web Site "projects" are created by using the File->New Web Site command in Visual Studio. They are very strange and should not be used unless you really need to. In most cases, you should use File->New Project.

Comment: "*My main idea is to make this a synonym of [tag:web]*" but **why**? [web] should be removed for being a crap useless tag. Not have even more crappy uselessness added to it. [Burninate the \[web\] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250190)

Comment: I do agree the web tag should be burinated -- I am not too familiar with the process of tag removal, but my assumption was that until the burination process may happen for `web`, `web-site-project` should be made a synonym of `web`.

Comment: What you're proposing is worse than just "don't do anything". At least that doesn't involve time and effort put in. Instead, you propose time and effort to be spent in order to increase the time and effort needed in the future to clean up. Instead of taking out the trash, just dump the entire bin inside the house but around the corner of where we're sitting. Either the tag is needed or not. Just growing the pile of trash until it reaches the ceiling isn't doing anybody any favours.

Comment: What happened today to this tag? There were some ~400 questions in the tag yesterday and today there are none. It was not synonymized, either.

Comment: @TylerH Well, not _yesterday_... I renamed it to [tag:vs-web-site-project] a few days ago, but didn't see this meta question.

Comment: @RyanM Thanks for the rename! I guess consider this one [meta-tag:status-completed]. Cleanup of the remaining questions can continue as a separate effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've at least *partly* fixed this tag by renaming it to [vs-web-site-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vs-web-site-project) (as suggested in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/421159/208273), though I hadn't seen this question at the time), which ought to help stem the tide of questions about a someone's project creating a web site.  The same has been done for [web-application-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-application-project), which is now [vs-web-application-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vs-web-application-project).

Separately, there are probably still a bunch of mistagged and/or otherwise bad questions in the tag, but that can be cleaned up separately.

Also, if anyone can fix the tag description to clarify that whatever this is (apparently) isn't a thing anymore, that might be good?  I don't use Visual Studio.

Comment: I don't suppose you could give the same treatment (a `vs-` prefix) to [tag:web-application-project]?

Comment: @TylerH Done: [tag:vs-web-application-project]

Answer (score 17):

Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are two different applications sharing only the first words of their name and the company who created them.  The description makes me think it's VS not VS Code, but neither application's current version has File -> New Web Site.

Visual Studio 2019 and 2022 do have File -> New -> Project which is a close fit for the recommended version; and is mostly used with stacks that don't have the concept of projects/solutions but instead just rely on the file system for grouping so I suspect it's referring to VS not VS Code.

Visual Studio project types unfortunately often have names that at best only make sense in a world where nothing outside of Microsoft exists; and often end up confusing even within it. The tag description you quoted suggests this is an example of the latter case.

At first glance through the recent questions it looks like, as usual no one is reading the tag description and none of the first 15 or 20 questions are using it correctly.  While I hesitate to judge a question by its title, if they're indicative I suspect a lot of them should be closed.

If we keep the tag, we need to prefix it with something to indicate that it's a Visual Studio specific item.  I have no idea how to name it to avoid confusion with normal VS web projects though.  An old, rarely used, recommended against, and apparently deprecated feature/project type that appears to have overwhelmingly collected off topic material is probably best left burned with no replacement tag.

Comment: I presume it refers to https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/muralidharan.d/Asp-Net-web-pages-with-visual-studio-2012/ - which was considered legacy and not recommended even back in 2012 when I started working with ASP.NET. It hasn't been part of Visual Studio for some time.

Comment: [Visual Studio - Website Vs Web Project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1583110/208273) seems to have some info on the differences, assuming that I understand correctly what these are supposed to refer to (I've never used either).

Answer (score 10):

> My main idea is to make this a synonym of [web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web) (which also seems to have its own broad issues).

Those issues are exactly why we should not create a synonym here. Merging a vague tag into a second vague tag does not help anyone find what they're looking for.

web is a very vague tag. If the question has another language-specific tag, like html, css, or php, then web contains no additional information. If the question does not have a language-specific tag - well, it should.

This suggests a similar fix for [web-site-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-site-project):

1. If a question is not about the Web Site Project feature of Visual Studio, then untag web-site-project and retag with a language specific tag.
2. If there is no appropriate language specific tag, for example because the author hasn't decided what language to use, then the question is likely not on topic for SO.
3. If a question *is* about the Web Site Project feature of Visual Studio, then leave it tagged web-site-project, and we can discuss renaming the tag to address confusion later. I would guess these will be around 20% of the questions, based on [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bweb-site-project%5D+%22visual+studio%22+is%3Aquestion).